# On-The-Fly Processing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic-dataset

what's on-the-fly processing in arcgis? saw this terminology while doing some research on mosaic dataset. Looking for a simple(less-complicated) answer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you provide the link in your question that defined this term?

Comment: Thanks,
well it says "On-the-fly processing generates mosaicked images on demand."

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to make this sound as "simple" as possible.

A mosaic dataset essentially stores the file location of the original individual raster files that make up your complete mosaic in a table.  The mosaic dataset also knows spatially where these files are.  So when you view a particular area on the map, the mosaic dataset will load the tiles that are in your viewing area.  This "on-the-fly" processing refers to how the mosaic dataset determines what tiles to load.  Using a mosaic dataset to view imagery or other detailed raster files can speed up rendering time so you have more time to look at your rasters, rather than waiting for them to "appear".

Comment: More generally, the phrase can mean that something is done in memory, and not written to disk. For example, ArcMap can project layers "on-the-fly" to a new coordinate reference system. The new coordinates are kept in memory.